# Async HTTP call and json using Nim

Tags: json, http, asynchronous, nim-lang

My code:

```
import std/[asyncdispatch, httpclient, json]

proc asyncProc(): Future[string] {.async.} =
  var client = newAsyncHttpClient()
  try:
    let response =  await client.getContent("https://randomuser.me/api/")
    result = parseJson(response).getStr()
  finally:
    client.close()

proc main() {.async.} =
    let results = await asyncProc()
    echo results
  

waitFor main()
```

Compiling this using:

**nim c -r --verbosity:0 -d:ssl fetch.nim**

Nothing is echoed out in the terminal, what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonNode` is an object variant. It provides getters such as `getStr()` to either return the value that the given `JsonNode` holds *or* the default value for the expected type.

In your example the following holds true:

```
let result = parseJson(response)
assert result.kind == JObject
assert result.getStr() == ""
```

You can convert the `JsonNode` to a string using the `$` operator: `$result`.

For example:

```
let response =  await client.getContent("https://randomuser.me/api/")
result = $parseJson(response)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, where in the manual can I get more info on this operator?

Comment: Sure thing, here's a [section on operators](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#lexical-analysis-operators), a [section on precedence](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#syntax-precedence), a [section on string-type](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-string-type), and a [system module](https://nim-lang.org/docs/dollars.html)